# In Html select, selected Property is not working

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

selected Property is not working

```
<select name="partner_name" id="partner_name" class="form-control" <?php echo $update_lock; ?> required>  
<option value="">Select</option>


    <?php

    foreach($partner_array as $value)
    {
            $partner_id = $value['UserNameID'];
            $partner_name = $value['full_name'];

            if($U_UserNameID==$partner_id)
            {

                    $s = 'selected=selected';
            }
            else
            {
                    $s = "";
            }



            echo "<option value='$partner_id' '$s'>".$partner_name."</option>";



    }  ?>
```

$update_lock = 'readonly' , it becomes readonly when user updates partner. Code was working previously . it suddenly stopped working.

```
<select name="partner_name" id="partner_name" class="form-control"  required >
<option value="">Select</option>


<option value='68' ''>A</option>
<option value='75' ''>B</option>
<option value='76' 'selected=selected'>C</option>
 <option value='77' ''>D</option>
<option value='78' ''>E</option>
```

i get this when i check resource.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: try `$s` instead of `'$s'`.

Comment: sorry forgot to write the question ,selected property is not working for selected partner

Comment: @nikhil previously i used $s only it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used java script to set the selected property instead of initializing variable in view part and its working nicely.

On **Form load event** I called JavaScript function:

```
<body onload="show_partner_id(<?php echo $partner_id?>">
```

In java script

```
function show_partner_id(partner_id)
{
     $('#selectid option[value="'+partner_id+'"]').attr('selected', 'selected');

}
```

Comment: Pretty sure it's a bad way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your generated Html is wrong, you should have somethink like this :

```
<select id="car">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" selected="selected">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

This will work properly:

```
<?php

foreach($partner_array as $value) {
        $partner_id = $value['UserNameID'];
        $partner_name = $value['full_name'];

        if($U_UserNameID==$partner_id) {
            echo "<option value='$partner_id' selected='true'>".$partner_name."</option>";
        } else {
            echo "<option value='$partner_id'>".$partner_name."</option>";
        }
}  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Use this code

```
<select name="partner_name" id="partner_name" class="form-control" <?php echo $update_lock; ?> required>  
<option value="">Select</option>


    <?php

    foreach($partner_array as $value)
    {
            $partner_id = $value['UserNameID'];
            $partner_name = $value['full_name'];

            if($U_UserNameID==$partner_id)
            {

                   // $s = 'selected=selected';

            ?>  
            <option value="$partner_id" selected><?php echo $partner_name;?></option>
          <?php         
            }
            else
            {
              ?>
            <option value="$partner_id"><?php echo $partner_name;?></option>
       <?php              
            }
            //echo "<option value='$partner_id' '$s'>".$partner_name."</option>";

    }  ?>
```

Comment: if I echo $s value with partner name it is displays as selected=selected but in option part it contains nothing.       <option value="76">ABC Partnerselected='selected'</option>

Comment: please check my code , i do not use $s variable any where, please use attribute for "selected" simple things frds